# Sign out of YouTube on iPhone video app uploader

Tags: iphone, video, youtube

I uploaded a video to my YouTube account from a friend's iPhone.  Now I want to to sign out so that he can upload videos from his own account, but it's no longer prompting to login to a YouTube account or giving an option to log out, it's just leaving my account signed in.  Help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- Start the YouTube app on the iPhone
- Select ".../More" at the bottom right
- Select "Sign out" at the top left

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you did it from the Camera Roll, I think you should go into the actual Youtube app on the phone and have him sign in with his/her account now, and I think that should fix it. Either that or what Iskra said

Answer (score 1):

If you've upgraded to 7+ OS you can sign out in the share screen when you are in camera roll > click on a video to share > click on youtube > scroll down to the bottom > click on your account username > click on option to log out.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has changed recently. Now you have to go to `Settings > Sign out`.

To get to `Settings`, look in the upper left corner and hit the button that has 3 lines on top of each other (like this = but with 3 lines). If that button is not there, hit the back arrow enough times until it shows up.

Once you click that button you'll see `Settings` on the left pane.

Click it, then on the next screen click `Sign Out`.

I have no idea why Youtube is making it so hard to sign out but, now you know how.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me, that option wasn't visible on the app. Instead, I started the process of uploading a video again from camera roll then when in the upload window before you take it to next stage I scrolled down to where it says user account ( my email or user name), touch screened that and there was an option to sign out popped up :D

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings and you should be able to find a log out option

Comment: Could you elaborate on where in settings this lies? The leading answer shows it in the … More tab of the app as opposed to settings.

Answer (score -1):

I just deleted the app then redownloaded it